# Statistics of the site showing the number of visitors/day has turned buggy?

Tags: bug

The statistics on the right hand of the site showing the number of visitor/day has turned buggy.

[image: on the site]

[On Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam):

[image: on Area 51]

**2014-04-26 20:47:00Z**

This thing just reoccurred and no it's not caching problem (opened it in private browse session).

Comment: Huh.  Numbers showing up properly on my end; might just be a caching problem?

Comment: It looks like there was some sort of server panic some hours back making sites across the network act wonky; I don't know the details, but it's probably related.